# Link from one page to another and toggle hidden div

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have a wordpress page with links to sections of a post.

Page:

```
<p><a href="http://204.128.208.7/link-test/#show1">Test 1</a></p>
<p><a href="http://204.128.208.7/link-test/#show2">Test 2</a></p>
<p><a href="http://204.128.208.7/link-test/#show3">Test 3</a></p>
<p><a href="http://204.128.208.7/link-test/#show4">Test 4</a></p>
```

Post:

```
<h4 id="show1" onclick="toggle('activeTransfers')">How to View Active Transfers<a id="arrowactiveTransfers">&#x25bc;</a></h4>
<div id="activeTransfers" style="display: none">
<p style="margin-left: 2em; margin-bottom: .5em">...</p>
<h4 onclick="toggle('activeTransfers')">Hide -</h4>
</div>
<p style="margin-bottom: 2em"> </p>
<h4 style="margin-bottom: .3em">Why an Item Is Not Included in the Automated Transfers</h4>
<p>The following are the main things that will keep an item off auto-transfers:</p>
<h4 id="show2" onclick="toggle('inventoryMasterMaintenance')">Inventory Master Maintenance<a id="arrowinventoryMasterMaintenance">&#x25bc;</a></h4>
<div id="inventoryMasterMaintenance" style="display: none;">
<p style="margin-left: 2em; margin-bottom: .5em">...</p>
<h4 onclick="toggle('inventoryMasterMaintenance')">Hide -</h4>
</div>
<p style="margin-bottom: 2em"> </p>
<h4 id="show3" onclick="toggle('vendorMaintenance')">Vendor Maintenance<a id="arrowvendorMaintenance">&#x25bc;</a></h4>
<div id="vendorMaintenance" style="display: none;">
<p style="margin-left: 2em; margin-bottom: .5em">...</p>
<h4 onclick="toggle('vendorMaintenance')">Hide -</h4>
</div>
<p style="margin-bottom: 2em"> </p>
<h4 id="show4" onclick="toggle('inventoryPriceMaintenance')">Inventory Price Maintenance<a id="arrowinventoryPriceMaintenance">&#x25bc;</a></h4>
<div id="inventoryPriceMaintenance" style="display: none;">
<p style="margin-left: 2em; margin-bottom: .5em">...</p>
<h4 onclick="toggle('inventoryPriceMaintenance')">Hide -</h4>
</div>
```

Recently I made it so I could toggle long sections of text, using the code below.

```
function toggle(id) {
 var element = document.getElementById(id);
 var text = document.getElementById("arrow" + id);
  if (element) {
  var display = element.style.display;

  if (display == "none") {
  element.style.display = "block";
  text.innerHTML = "&#9650;";

  } else {
  element.style.display = "none";
  text.innerHTML = "&#x25bc;";
  }
 }
}
```

But now when I use the links from the page to the post it just shows the section titles. I would like it if the link also toggled the section open.

I have no idea how to achieve this or if it is even possible; can someone please help me?

Comment: use `window.location.hash` to get the id and open it

Comment: Could you explain a little further?

Comment: `window.location.hash` will get the `#` part of the url, there should be one if you click one of the links (eg show1), you can then pass this into your toggle function.  Can't remember if the hash is returned with the value but you can just remove it if it does

Comment: Ok, thank you so much!